# use 'this' keyword in object inside method in Vuejs

Tags: object, methods, vuejs2, vue-component

In a Vue component, I have a method like as below

```
methods: {
   submitMethod() {
     let objA = {
       id: this.id,
       this.anObject
     }
   }
 }
```

It gives, Syntax Error: this is a reserved word.

how to use the object, which is defined in somewhere like data() or computed, in the object of the method in Vue.js?

One workaround is that, this.anObject can be assigned to local variable and use that variable inside objA as below

```
submitMethod() {
    let anObject = this.anObject
    let objA = {
        id: this.id,
        anObject
     }
}
```

But, is there a way to use this.anObject directly inside objA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the object restSpread operator, you can use it:

```
methods: {
   submitMethod() {
     let objA = {
       id: this.id,
       ...this.anObject
     }
   }
 }
```

Otherwise, you can use Object.assign:

```
methods: {
   submitMethod() {
     let objA = Object.assign(this.anObject, {
       id: this.id,
     })
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

thats because your JSON is invalid. it should be like

```
let objA = {
    id: this.id,
    anObject: this.anObject
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use this keyword with the help of copy this keyword as a local variable.

```
methods: {
  submitMethod() {
    let _this = this;
    let objA = Object.assign(this.anObject, {
       id: _this.id,
    })
  }
}
```